# C# random char between first letter to special char [=]

Tags: c#, get, save, equals

My problem is with getting values from .txt file.
I have this for example[without enter]:

```
damage=20 big explosion=50 rangeweapon=50.0
```

and I want to get these values after "=". Just to make a `string[]` with something like that:

```
damage=20
big explosion=50
rangeweapon=50.0
```

I got some other mechanic but i want to find universal mechanic to get all values into `string[]` and then just check it in switch.
Thank You.

Comment: do you simply want `string[] values = text.Split(" ");`

Comment: @Jonesy - wont work because of "big explosion"

Comment: So, people - it is possible to change "damage=20" only into integer value"? Now i just delete [replace] the "damage=" into "" and then conver into integer...

Comment: do you have control over the .txt file? if so why not separate your values by a comma "," or pipe "|" instead of just a space " "? Then it is easier to parse.

Comment: I a modder and this is a default game file. This is "xml" but... in my computer Linq wont work. Visual see this, but game not see "namespace"... :(

Comment: I don't see any xml here, not sure what you mean.

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in a hex editor to make sure there's not some other character there?

Comment: Yeah, HEX shows this is " " between values and between "big explosions"[example value].

Comment: So the values for ` big ` are 20, 62, 69, 67, 20?

Comment: The "big explosion" is example. Not is in file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try to solve your problem with regex. I found one solution that is not best solution.
May be it can help or guide you to find best solution.

Please try like this

```
string operation = "damage=20 big explosion=50 rangeweapon=50.0";

string[] wordText = Regex.Split(operation, @"(\=\d+\.?\d?)");  
/*for split word but result array has last value that empty you will delete its*/

string[] wordValue = Regex.Split(operation, @"(\s*\D+\=)");  /*for split digit that is value of word but result array has first value that empty you will delete its*/
```

After that you can join or do anything you want with those array.

Comment: This code I understand and very small. Only I needed to remove other characters what are not in my example code. Work fine. Now i must find a way to get a damage for pistol, damage for others... I know about Contains and i will use this. Thanks a much. This is solution for me.

Comment: PS. Could You explain the <code>@"(\s*\D+\="</code>? Thank You.

Comment: \s* = 0-n whitespace, \D+ = 1-n not digit, \= is mean =, () = group

you can see more information and test your reg at http://www.phpliveregex.com/  is same concept as another programming language.

Answer (score 0):

This should parse the string you describe, but keep in mind it isn't very robust and has no error handling.

```
string stringToParse = "damage=20 big explosion=50 rangeweapon=50.0";
string[] values = stringToParse.Split(' ');
Dictionary<string, double> parsedValues = new Dictionary<string, double>();

string temp = "";
foreach (var value in values)
{
    if (value.Contains('='))
    {
       string[] keyValue = value.Split('=');
       parsedValues.Add(temp + keyValue[0], Double.Parse(keyValue[1]));
       temp = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        temp += value + ' ';
    }
}
```

After this, the parsedValues dictionary should have the information you're looking for.

Comment: Tested, good code but i must change some values of this. I must learn about Dictonary, because i do not know what is this doing :(

Comment: It is a worthwhile thing to know how to use, even if you are new to C#. Scrolling down to the 'Examples' section of this link may be a good place to start. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: I will try to learn, but about Your code - not working good like code from "cavaliercyber", but thank You for Your support :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert about it, but what about using a [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest code in the world, but will work for your situation.

```
        string input = "damage=20 big explosion=50 rangeweapon=50.0";
        string[] parts = input.Split('=');
        Dictionary<string, double> dict = new Dictionary<string, double>();

        for (int i = 0; i < (parts.Length - 1); i++)
        {
            string key = i==0?parts[i]:parts[i].Substring(parts[i].IndexOf(' '));
            string value = i==parts.Length-2?parts[i+1]:parts[i + 1].Substring(0, parts[i + 1].IndexOf(' '));
            dict.Add(key.Trim(), Double.Parse(value));
        }

        foreach (var el in dict)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key {0} contains value {1}", el.Key, el.Value);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to read number from text.You can save your data in text like this.

damage=20,big explosion=50,rangeweapon=50. And read from text via File.ReadAllLines().

```
    string[] Lines;
    string[] myArray;
    Lines = File.ReadAllLines(your file path);



        for (int i = 0; i < Lines.Length; i++)
         {
                    myArray = Lines[i].Split(',');

         }
         for (int j = 0; j < myArray .Length; j++)
         {
                        string x =myArray [j].ToString();
                        x = Regex.Replace(x, "[^0-9.]", "");

                        Console.WriteLine(x);
         }
```